# Parse and reformat telephone number

Tags: java, phone-number

I need to write a piece of code that counts how many numbers the user enters. If the user enters more numbers than a typical phone number (for example, by entering `9589889898989`), the program must display an error and ask the user to reenter the number. If the user inputs a correct number (e.g,. `5083588745`), the program should print the number in the correct format. How can I do this?

**NOTE:** Everything is complete besides the code that that can read the individual numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your 10 digit #.");
    long nrmNum = 1111111111;
    long phoneFmt = 0l;
    phoneFmt = (long) input.nextDouble();
    //get a 12 digits String, filling with left '0′ (on the prefix)

    java.text.DecimalFormat phoneDecimalFmt =
      new java.text.DecimalFormat("0000000000");

    String phoneRawString = phoneDecimalFmt.format(phoneFmt);

    java.text.MessageFormat phoneMsgFmt =
      new java.text.MessageFormat("({0}) - {1} - {2}");
    //suposing a grouping of 3-3-4
    String[] phoneNumArr = {
      phoneRawString.substring(0, 3),
      phoneRawString.substring(3, 6),
      phoneRawString.substring(6)
    };
    nrmNum /= 1;
    if (phoneFmt == nrmNum) {
        System.out.println("Your Phone number is:");
        System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
    } else {
        System.out.print("Please input 10 numbers for the phone#");
        System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "goes over"? That a user inputs more than 10 digits? The purpose of the program is not clear to me. You want that all numbers consisting of less than 11 digits are accepted? And what is your actual question?

Comment: as such there is no international standard about phone numbers, some countries have as short as 6 digit number while some others have as long as 13digits number. You cant exactly determine the valid number, provided user might include country code, or international/national dialing (0/00).

Comment: @user2180880: Just to be clear: For the purpose of your program what do you consider a "correct number"? ("At most 10 digits long.", "Exactly 10 digits long.", ...)

Comment: The number needs to be exactly 10 digits long